# Leaflet.js popups are visible when page loads

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using this plugin for a project. When i create popup they are activated when the loads. I want them to open when user clicks on the marker. Any help?

```js
const mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([40.399245, 49.876386], 10);
const tile = L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
  maxZoom: 18,
  id: 'mapbox.streets',
  accessToken: 'TOKEN'
}).addTo(mymap);

const mapIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'assets/image/icons/marker.png',
  iconSize: [40, 40],
  iconAnchor: [20, 20]
})


const marker = L.marker([40.399245, 49.876386], { icon: mapIcon }).addTo(mymap);
const marker = L.marker([40.399245, 49.876386], { icon: mapIcon }).addTo(mymap);
var popup = L.popup({}).setContent('content')

marker.bindPopup(popup).openPopup();
marker.setLatLng([40.399245, 49.876386]).addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: How did you implement the popups? Please post some code so we can help you better.

Comment: @MMM i bound it to a marker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This little line of code is the culprit:

```
marker.bindPopup(popup).openPopup();
```

On this line you're binding the popup to a marker *and then opening the popup right away.* Leaving out the `openPopup()` method should fix your problem.

```
marker.bindPopup(popup);
```

As per the [Leaflet documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#popup):

> **Usage example**
>
> If you want to just bind a popup to marker click **and then open it**, it's really easy:
>
> `marker.bindPopup(popupContent).openPopup();`